# Rails - how do you display data from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im fairly new to Rails and i am simply trying to display the user_id of a record in a sqlite3 database on a page. Here is my code:

### Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :user_id
  has_one :user_id
end
```

### Controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.find(0)
  end
end
```

### View

```
<%= User.users.user_id %>
```

Im sure im making a silly mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively in your view:

```
<% User.all.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.id %>
<% end %>
```

This will print out the user_id for all the records in User

Comment: In addtion, try dropping into a `rails console` to see what User.find(0) returns (in this case most likely an error). That way you know what you're sending to your view

Comment: That worked! @leflings but im guessing thats not the right way to do it? Its the first time ive connected successfully to the database though woo!

Comment: @Tim Thats usually not the right way to it, no. I would suggest reading abit about the MVC-architecture. Alternatively start with a good book/tutorial (i can really recommend [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) ). Maybe check out [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) - it's a fun way to get started, and will teach you some fundamentals.

Comment: I just started the project so I thought I would try and get a page to display the user_id from the users table. Eventually, I will need to change user_id 0 to equal the user_id of the person logged in.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want a UID for a user object it's fairly standard to let rails sort this out for you, so you just generate the required attributes of your table and don't include user_id. However it might be the case you want this user_id in which case ignore what I just said.
You don't need the has_one relation unless you have another model named user_id (which is possible I guess)

The index method is generally meant to return all users, or at least a subset (if you use pagination for example) I would therefore recommend using the following in an index method

```
User.find :all
```

Notice I have left the brackets off, it doesn't make a difference but is a rails convention (it make it looks more like a DSL).

To return 1 user you might want a method like this

```
# GET /posts/1
def show
   @user = User.first      
end
```

But convention states the id would be specified by url sent, so it might look more like this

```
# GET /posts/1
def show
   @user = User.find params[:id]      
end
```

if you then access a url like the one specified above the show method (/posts/1, where 1 is the ID)

The view for this method should look something like this:

```
<%= @user.user_id %>
```

Note the @user is a member variable passed to the view by the show method, in this case an instance of a user with the id 1, and you are accessing the user_id attribute of that instance so you don't need the `User.` as this would be calling on a class method not a method of an instance of the user object.

To answer your specific question it should look more like

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :user_id
end
```

Controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.first
  end 
end
```

Accessing the show view with /users/0

The View would contain

```
<%= @user.user_id %>
```

EDIT:

To display the user logged in you will probably need a user session object which is created when a user logs in and destroyed when the user logs out. The user session object should have an associated user object, you can then query the user_session object for which user is logged.

I strongly recommend using [authlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic), it's simple enough to know whats going on but does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the `User.find(0)` here? Doesn't the `ID` start with one? To be safe, do

```
@user = User.first
```

The  in the view, you would do

```
<%= @user.user_id %>
```

Comment: Code looks better already but still get an error:

uninitialized constant User::UserId

Answer (score 0):

To print the whole DB use;

```
Model.all
```

e.g

```
User.all
```